# Factory_girl and RSpec: undefined method `new' for Test:Module

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, factory-bot

I generated the following scaffold (using Ruby 2.2.0, rails 4.1.8, postgres):

```
 rails g scaffold Test user:references text:references data:hstore
```

In my test_spec.rb:

```
require 'rails_helper'

RSpec.describe Test, :type => :model do
  describe 'User generates a test' do
    before do
      @text = create(:text, content: "Cats eat mice")
      @user = create(:user)
      @test = create(:test)
    end
...
```

When I run rspec the test fails with the following message:

```
Failure/Error: @test = create(:test)
 NoMethodError:
   undefined method `new' for Test:Module
 # ./spec/models/test_spec.rb:8:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

When I test other models (user, text) everything works well, only the Test model fails. Calling Test.create(...) in rspec file also fails. Creating new test in rails console works. Any ideas how to fix this?

Comment: You have an issue with `Test` keyword. `Test` should be a `class` (from `ActiveRecord::Base`), not a `Module`. Check all your application to see if a `module Test` is defined.

Comment: That's right! Changed 'Test' to 'ReadingTest' and it all works now. THX!

Answer (score 1):

With the default configuration, Rails defines the module constant `Test`, so Ruby doesn't autoload your `test.rb` file when FactoryGirl does a `Test.new` as part of your `:test` factory.

You can install Rails without the `Test` infrastructure by using the `-T` switch, in which case it won't define the `Test` module and you should be fine.

If Rails is already configured, you can put the following in your `rails_helper.rb` file to remove the `Test` constant and you should be ok as well:

```
Object.send(:remove_const, :Test)
```